# I want to display values from Database to jTable

Tags: java, database, eclipse, jtable

I have a Java program called `employeeRecords`, which I use to do  CRUD operations in a  SQL Server database.

I have another program called `Table` which is a jTable program.  I need to display `employeeRecords` values into my jTable. I know how to display a record in textField  but not in jTable columns.

If it matters I'm using Eclipse Mars.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start by having a look at [How to Use Tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html)

The answer is quite complex, depending on what you want to achieve.

I'd suggest starting by creating a simple POJO to hold the data from the database, personally, this makes the management much easier...

```
public class Employee {
    // Fields, getters and setters
}
```

Next, you'll want a `TableModel` to manage all the instances of `Employee`...

```
public class EmployeeTableModel extends AbstractTableModel {
    private List<Employee> employees;

    public EmployeeTableModel(List<Employee> employees) {
        this.employees = new ArrayList<>(employees);
    }

    @Override
    public int getRowCount() {
        return employees.size();
    }

    @Override
    public int getColumnCount() {
        return how ever many fields you want to display;
    }

    @Override
    public String getColumnName(int column) {
        String name = "??";
        switch (column) {
            case 0:
                name = "What every this column represents"
                break;
                .
                .
                .
        }
        return name;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
        Employee employee = employees.get(rowIndex);
        Object value = null;
        switch (columnIndex) {
            case 0:
                value = employee.getXxx();
                break;
                .
                .
                .
        }
        return value;
    }


}
```

Personally, I find it easier to have a custom table for each POJO, as it allows you manage the individual rows/objects more easily, but that's me

Next, you need to load the data from the database and populate the table model...

```
public EmployeeTableModel getEmployeeTableModel() throws SQLException {
    Connection con = ...;
    EmployeeTableModel model = null;
    try (PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement("select * from employeRecords")) {
        try (ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery()) {
            List<Employee> employees = new ArrayList<>(25);
            while (rs.next()) {
                Employee employee = new Employee();
                employee.setXxx(rs.getString("Xxx"));
                //...
            }
            model = new EmployeeTableModel(employees);
        }
    }
    return model;
}
```

Finally, you need to apply the model to a instance of `JTableModel`

```
public class SomeUIClass extends JPanel {
    //...
    private JTable table;
    //...

    public void someMethodYouNeedToCallWhenYouWantToReloadTheModel() {
        try {
            table.setModel(getEmployeeTableModel());
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanq,and i have perfmng console crude operations with employeeRecords java programn  evrythng is perfct till here and now i need to design UI for crude operations first of all i want to display  records into jtable with n there is access to my employeeRecrds and jtable program also now i need code for display records in jtable,i created a button and i gave an id in jTable program  now when im click that button it would display that record into jtable.

Comment: Without knowing the structure of the database record, that's about the best I can do. Your question is already over broad, perhaps you should have a look at [Creating a GUI With JFC/Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/), [How to Use Buttons, Check Boxes, and Radio Buttons](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html) and 
[How to Write an Action Listeners](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html) for more examples

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you know how to access the database etc but to print the data to the JTable use this constructor.
 `JTable(Vector rowData, Vector columnNames)
Constructs a JTable to display the values in the Vector of Vectors, rowData, with column names, columnNames.`

Just remember that the rowData parameter is a Vector of Vectors, with position 0 being the first row under the headings etc.

If this doesn't answet your question please be a little bit more specific and I will see what I can help you with